# Keras + TensorFlow prepend a processing layer to a trained network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to prepend a preprocessing layer to a pre-trained network. This is the code I'm working on:

```
orig_model = applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
orig_model.load_weights(weights_path)

preproc_layer = Lambda(preprocess, input_shape=(3,224,224), output_shape=(3,224,224))

model = Sequential()
model.add(preproc_layer)

all_layers = orig_model.layers
for l in all_layers:
    config = l.get_config()
    copy = layers.deserialize({'class_name':l.__class__.__name__, 'config': config})
    weights = l.get_weights()
    copy.set_weights(weights)
    model.add(copy)
```

Where preprocess is:

```
preprocess(x):
    x = x[::-1, ...]
    x = K.bias_add(x, vgg_mean, data_format='channels_first')
```

It works for the first `InputLayer` but throws me an error at `copy.set_weights(weights)` for the second (`Conv2D`) layer:

```
 You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "block1_conv1" with a  weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 0 weights.
```

I found something similar on Google: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4812. Here they suggest setting `trainable = True` for the layer, but this doesn't work in my case.

Do you have any suggestions? Keras version is 2.1.5, Tensorflow 1.6.0